# Finding the value type of an Iterator

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, lambda

I have a template parameter `InIter` in one of my overloaded functions, and I need to call a `for_each_n` to loop with `InIter` for `x` iterations, which I don't have any trouble doing. But I'm having trouble getting the **value type** of the iterator, to give an example:

```
//invalid lambda function
for_each_n(param1, param2, param3,
    [val](InIter it) {
        *it = val;
    });
```

this however does not work, I need to pass in the value type of InIter it rather than the entire iterator. This example does work below, but obviously I can't just leave the type `std::size_t` or I'll be forced to create only `std::size_t` containers.

```
for_each_n(param1, param2, param3,
    [val](std::size_t& v){
        v = val;
    });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### How to do it..

To get the value-type of an iterator you should use [`std::iterator_traits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits) from [`<iterator>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iterator), this will make it very easy to obtained the wrapped *value_type*, as well as being generic enough so that you can even use it with *pointers*.

```
std::iterator_traits<InIter>::value_type
```

```cpp
std::iterator_traits<char       *>::value_type                     => char
std::iterator_traits<char const *>::value_type                     => char const
```

```cpp
std::iterator_traits<std::vector<int>::iterator      >::value_type => int
std::iterator_traits<std::vector<int>::const_iterator>::value_type => int const
```

---

#### Alternative

If you are writing *C++11*, and have an instance of `InIter`, there's also the posibility of using  `decltype` to obtain the type of `*it`, which effectively (in most/all cases) is the same as what `std::iterator_traits<T>::value` would yield.

---

#### Implementation

Judging from your example snippets it seems that you, instead of wanting the *value_type* of the iterator, are more interested in the actual *reference-type*, below is a sample implementation:

```
for_each_n(param1, param2, param3,
  [val](typename std::iterator_traits<InIter>::reference v){
    v = val;
  }
);
```

```cpp
for_each_n(param1, param2, param3, [val](decltype(*some_it) v){
  v = val;
});
```

Comment: A `using` wrapper of interest: `template<class Iterator>using value_type_t=typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type;`, which shortens access to `value_type_t<It>`.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`std::iterator_traits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits).  You can use `std::iterator_traits<InIter>::value_type` to reference the value type of the iterator. This will work for both custom iterators and pointers, because of the template specializations.  So if `InIter` is `T*` or `const T*` for some `T`, you will get the correct value type.

Custom iterators define a `value_type` member type directly, but when writing code that can handle any type of iterator it's not safe to use `InIter::value_type` to reference the value type of the iterator because `InIter` might be just a pointer, which has no `value_type` member type.

Comment: +1, but direct access to `iterator::value_type` should be discouraged (if you have no information).  Emphasize the `iterator_traits` approach more.