# How to get the value type of an iterator in a template declaration?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

For this template declaration:

```
template <class Iterator>
typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type Mean(Iterator begin, Iterator end);
```

I would like to simplify the value_type typename with a "using declaration" or typedef.  So that it is a easier to read the return type.  Is there a way to do this in the declaration?

Related posts
[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24208108/finding-the-value-type-of-an-iterator)
[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46801407/c-any-iterator-with-a-specific-value-type)

Comment: Humorous Answer: `auto Mean(Iterator begin, Iterator end);`

Comment: Half joking solution: compile as C++20 and use `std::iter_value_t`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an template alias like

```
template <typename Iterator>
using iterator_value_type_t = typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type;
```

and then you can use that with your function like

```
template <class Iterator>
iterator_value_type_t<Iterator> Mean(Iterator begin, Iterator end);
```

---

If you want to allow specifying a custom return type then you can move the return type into the template parameter list like

```
template <class Iterator, 
          class ReturnType = typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type>
ReturnType Mean(Iterator begin, Iterator end);
```

Comment: I'm trying to compile your answer as a declaration like so, does not compile:
```template <class Iterator>
using value_type_t = typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type;
value_type_t<Iterator> Mean(Iterator begin, Iterator end);```

Comment: @TysonHilmer Works fine [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/42dace4eb1447829)

Comment: Ahh, I understand now.  Two template declarations, or alternatively a second template parameter.  Perfect and thanks so much :) !

Answer (score 0):

You can create an alias to `std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type`:

```
template <class It>
using itval= std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type;

//And use it:template <class Iterator>
itval<Iterator> Mean(Iterator begin, Iterator end);
```

In general for templates you should use the `using` keyword. Typedef can't support templates.